# How to keep indent of nested bullet list across pages?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, itemize

I have a nested bullet list which begins at the end of one page and ends in the next one.
However, when going across pages, the indentation of the list is not kept and the bullet is justified to the left of the page.

How can I prevent this? Is it better to push the whole list to the next page?

Code:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Compute a baseline score $s$ of the model $m$ on a data set $D$
    \item For each feature $i$:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Randomly shuffle feature $i$ (a column in $D$) to obtain a perturbed data set $D_{i}$
        \item Compute the score $s_i$ of model $m$ on the data set $D_{i}$
        \item Compute the importance of feature $i$, $importance_i$, as:
        \begin{equation}
            importance_i = s - s_i
        \end{equation}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Result:
[image]

P.S.: Is there a way to center 3.6 the same as 3.7?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see  what the problem is, neither for the bullets, nor for equation numbers.

Comment: Are you using the book class? The indent is the same but the margins switch between even and odd pages.

Comment: Please give a` MWE` instead of a snippet  that we can compile and reveals what you the problem is.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without a complete MWE, but its probably because of a two-sided layout with differe margins on even and odd pages. For your PS: just put the equation outside the itemize

Comment: the nesting is relative to the text block not to the edge of the page, and is kept over the page break. unrelated but never use the default math italic for words: use `$\mathit{importance}_i$` not `$importance_i$` 3.6 is centred in the current text width, which is reduced because of the list. If the equation is part of the list item that is what you want, otherwise place the equation after the list.

Comment: The base class is indeed the book class. I can understand the problem deriving from even/odd pages, however when looking at it as a pdf I can clearly see the last point being at a different indentation wrt the penultimate one. @DavidCarlisle I changed to mathit however I don't see any visual difference, is this expected? As for the equation it is indeed part of the list but I don't like seeing it off-centered wrt 3.7, would it be wrong to move it out of the list?

Comment: perhaps you just want to use the`[oneside]` option so the page margins are the same.  For the other questions  the math font has wide sidebearings and no ligatures so that adjacent letters look like a product of variables not a word (I could tell from your image, without looking at the code:-) try using the word `difficult` for a more obvious case as f is very different. For the equation if you center it on the text block not the item, then any reader will see it as after the list not as part of the list item so it is your choice as author whether that is what you want,

Comment: are you sure the indent is different (measure from the left edge of that headline rule, not from the page edge) It is highly unlikely to be different as it is hard (almost impossible) to make it vary at a page break in TeX, You have (still) provided no test case so no one other than you can test.

Comment: I haven't provided the example because I added more text in one of the previous pages and the problem fixed itself, so to speak :-) but I am more inclined to believe I was wrong rather than all of you in saying that the indent was correct. thanks for all the help!

Comment: At least, use the showframe package of the showframe option of geometry to see what the indentation actually is.